# Arcs of a circle Geometry and angles

Tags: geometry, circles

If a central angle of measure $30°$ is subtended by a circular arc of length $6\,\mathrm{m}$, how many meters in length is the radius of the circle?

**A.** $\frac{π}{36}$

**В.** $\frac{1}{5}$

**С.** $π$

**D.** $\frac{36}{π}$

**E.** $180$

[image]

---

How do I find out what the radius length of the angle is? The answer is (D) by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the circle's circumference be given by $C$, let it's diameter = $d$, it's radius $r$.

The ratio of the arc of the circle to the circumference is equal to the ratio of the $30$ degree angle to the measure of a circle = $360^\circ$:

$$\dfrac{6}{C} = \dfrac{30}{360} = \dfrac{1}{12}\quad \implies \quad C = 6\times 12  \implies C=72$$

Using the formula for circumference of a circle: $C = d\pi = 2\pi r$, and solving for r:

$$C = 72 = 2 \pi r $$ $$\implies r = \dfrac{72}{2\pi} = \dfrac{36}{\pi}$$

Comment: is this off by a factor of 10? I think you meant 72 after reductions. Regards

Comment: Yes, indeed!...

Comment: Is this making sense, Little Jon?

Comment: Yes this is a valid answer Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The full circle has perimeter $\frac{360^\circ}{30^\circ}\cdot 6\,\mathrm m=72\,\mathrm m$. As this must equal $2\pi r$, we find $r=\frac{36}\pi\,\mathrm m$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The circumference of a circle of radius $r$ is $\pi r$. The $30^\circ$ angle is $\frac{30}{360}=\frac1{12}$ of the total angle at the centre of the circle, so $6$ metres is $\frac1{12}$ of the circumference of the circle. The whole circumference is therefore $6\cdot12=72$ metres, which, as already noted, is $2\pi r$. Therefore $r$ is ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Length of the arc is $L_\alpha = \alpha r$, so $r = \frac {L_\alpha}\alpha = \frac 6{\pi/6} = \frac {36}\pi$

Answer (score 0):

The way that you can solve this is by using the following formula:

$$A=\frac{n}{360}\pi{r^2}$$

Hope that helps you out!  I can't figure out how to type in the equation!